# Why doesn't the choice of normalization convention matter for 2D discrete fourier transforms

Tags: python, fft, normalization, amplitude

I am trying to produce a power spectrum for a 2D image.

I understand how the choice of normalization convention doesn't matter if you're forward transforming and then inverse transforming so long as the product of both normalization constants is 1/N^2.

But if I have an image and I'm forward fourier transforming it, then going on to produce a power spectrum, surely it should effect the amplitude of the power spectrum whether I have a normalization constant of 1/N^2 or 1/N or none at all?

What is it I am not understanding here? Please help! Thanks in advance.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
image = np.random.rand(10,10)
fourierimage = np.fft.fft2(image)
fourierimage = fftpack.fftshift(fourierimage)
powerspec2D = np.absolute(fourierimage)**2

# I then calculate the azimuthally averaged 1D power spectrum 
#   from powerspec2D to give my final result
```

My point is wouldn't it effect the final amplitude of my power spec if start putting in factors of 1/N^2 e.g.:

fourierimage = (1/image.size)np.fft.fft2(image)

Comment: Might be better for [math.se]

Comment: Can you give minimal code?

Comment: I've added a simple example of code